# Sklearn model coefficients and predict mismatch in linear_model

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, data-science

I am relatively new to ML and sklearn and I am trying to train a linear model for input data with 6 different features using ***linear_model.Lasso*** with different values of the regularization parameter. Given that ***X*** and ***y*** are my input parameters for the model, I can not figure out why I keep getting different values by executing these 2 expressions:

```
sum(model.coef_*X[0])
Out[94]: -0.4895022980752311

model.predict(X[0])
Out[95]: array([ 2.08767122])
```

Ideally I would expect that the model coefficients would correspond to a given feature in the dataset and that both expressions would return exactly the same value.

Here is the sample of the code:

```
input_file = 'Spud_startup_analysis.xlsx'
data_input_generic = pd.read_excel(input_file, skiprows = 0, sheetname='DataSet')
data = data_input_generic.as_matrix()
X = data[:, 0:-1]
y = data[:,-1]
model = linear_model.Lasso(alpha = 0.1)
model.fit(X, y)
```

does it have something to do with dimensions of the input matrices?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the intercept-term, which is part of the optimization [by default](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Lasso.html) (`fit_intercept`).

```
class sklearn.linear_model.Lasso(alpha=1.0, fit_intercept=True, normalize=False,
    precompute=False, copy_X=True, max_iter=1000, tol=0.0001, warm_start=False,
    positive=False, random_state=None, selection=’cyclic’)[source]
```

> fit_intercept : boolean
>
> whether to calculate the intercept for this model. If set to false, no intercept will be used in calculations (e.g. data is expected to be already centered).

You can grab it with `model.intercept_` after fitting.

Internally, predict [does](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b46/sklearn/linear_model/base.py#L236):

```
return safe_sparse_dot(X, self.coef_.T,
                       dense_output=True) + self.intercept_
```

Comment: ah...the x_0 coefficient. Definitely. Thanks a lot